# Spark Streaming with Pubsub-BigTable Performance Issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-bigtable

**Context:** I am working on a spark streaming pipeline to achieve a high throughput of 200K+ RPS. The pipeline is **reading from Pubsub using multiple custom receiver streams (60-80) and writing to BigTable** with some custom transformations in between to collect metrics (no shuffles). I have attached the DAG below. Each micro-batch has 2 jobs, 1 for the empty check, and 1 for the write action. The batch interval is 10s. 5-10 concurrent jobs. The number of executors (5cores/13g, 3 executors per GCP n1-standard-16 machine) is more than the number of streams with 25 nodes cluster.

I am facing an issue of inconsistent processing time which is causing the pipeline to become unstable for sometime after a few hours. This causes a drop in throughput. For example, sometimes the processing time for a batch of 740K records is around 9s while for 500K records it goes up to 1.3 mins (see attached screenshots) below.

I checked the task execution times and could see that for 500K batch the task parallelism is not sufficient while for 740K batch parallelism is high (see attached screenshots). Can somebody help and provide a suggestion on how to tackle such issues and achieve consistent processing time? Or any other suggestion in general about spark streaming using custom receivers for PubSub?

[image]

[image]

DAG for the pipeline:
[image]

Task execution graph for 740K batch job:
[image]

Task execution graph for 500K batch job:
[image]

[image]

Additional Spark configurations used,

"spark.executor.instances": "90"

"spark.executor.heartbeat.maxFailures": "6",

"spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts": "4",

"spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval": "1h",

"spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval": "1h",

"spark.task.maxFailure": "8",

"spark.streaming.concurrentJobs": "10",

"spark.streaming.numStreams": "80",

"spark.scheduler.allocation.file": "/usr/lib/spark/conf/fairscheduler.xml",

"spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true"

Comment: Have you used any specific spark configuration labels, like parallelism?

Comment: Apart from executor cores and memory, these are additional spark configurations I am using,

"spark.executor.instances": "90",
"spark.executor.heartbeat.maxFailures": "6",
"spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts": "4",
"spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval": "1h",
"spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval": "1h",
"spark.task.maxFailure": "8",
"spark.streaming.concurrentJobs": "10",
"spark.scheduler.allocation.file": "/usr/lib/spark/conf/fairscheduler.xml",
"spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more question, do you use Spark within Dataproc cluster? As an addition, I would like to share with you my consideration about giving a try to use Dataflow for your case. It provides autoscaling of resources and dynamic work rebalancing, which minimize pipeline latency, maximize resource utilization. You can take a look for ready solution [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb104-bigtable-cbt/#0)